# Flutter App launch doesn't work in VS Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I have a project with two friends, where we are building an app. We use Azure DevOps for downloading and uploading our changes and VS Code for writing the code. Whenever I run the main.dart file it says:

```
Set the 'program' value in your launch config (eg 'bin/main.dart') then launch again
```

So I set the program value in the launch.json file do bin/main.dart. I also saw some people with the same problem, that changed it to lib/main.dart. In my project it is in a lib folder, but I tried both anyway. Both gives the same result:

```
ProcessException: No such file or directory...

and 

Your launch config references a program that does not exist. If you have problems launching, check the "program" field in your ".vscode/launch.json" file.
```

Does anyone know what to do ?

Some people also deleted the .vscode folder and the launch.json file within. I did the same, however it still pops up when I run the file.

I also tried to create a new launch.json file, that didn't change anything neither.

There's no problem with flutter itself. I ran the flutter doctor multiple times and everything is working.

That's how it is at the moment:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a launcher file.

[image]

Or manually

Replace `so_march` with your project name

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "so_march",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": "lib/main.dart", // it comes by default
            // "deviceId": "c"
        },
        {
            "name": "so_march (profile mode)",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "profile"
        },
        {
            "name": "so_march (release mode)",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "release"
        }
    ]
}
```

And it locate on

[image]

Comment: It is still giving me the same error

Comment: make sure you are on the root directory of your flutter project as shown on last image & program must indicate to your main.dart

Comment: I put a picture of the current project in the description. It still doesn't work as it is at the moment

Comment: you need to go one level deeper from current location, as you can see on my image, `SO_MARCH` is my project name which is showing just after the Explorer (top left)

Comment: What do you mean by going one level deeper. Isn't the only difference that I have another folder ? Sorry for that many questions but I don't really understand it.

Comment: You aren't on your flutter project root directory, open `flutter_application_sd` instead of `screwdriverApp...`